# PYQT5 add multiple images to window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I can't add two images to one window in Python. **I've looked at other threads on the forum and they didn't help**. Only 1 is added with the QImage function. I want both the original image and the image that I will make changes to appear in the program. I just couldn't add the original image, operations on normal image etc. I can do it, no problem. They say QPixmap or something, but I don't understand. Codes are attached:

```
    def openImage(self,image_label):
    image_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", 
            "", "PNG Files (*.png);;JPG Files (*.jpeg *.jpg );;Bitmap Files (*.bmp);;\
            GIF Files (*.gif)")
    
    if image_file:
        self.parent.zoom_factor = 1
        self.parent.print_act.setEnabled(True)
        self.parent.updateActions()

        self.parent.brightness_slider.setValue(0)

        image_format = self.image.format()
        self.image = QImage(image_file) #manipulated area
        self.original_image = self.image.copy() #Original image

        self.setPixmap(QPixmap().fromImage(self.image))
        self.resize(self.pixmap().size())
    elif image_file == "":
        # User selected Cancel
        pass

    else:
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", 
            "Unable to open image.", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Thank you very much in advance. The model I want to make is this;
[image]

I just threw it out so you can understand how I want to do it. It's not because you write a project for me from scratch.

Comment: Supposing the above code refers to a QLabel, you need to add *another* QLabel to your window and show the other image there. Without a [mre] we cannot really answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using QImage you can use QLabel and apply QPixmap and also arrange them in vertical layout.

Like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
image_one = QLabel()
image_two = QLabel()
def set_image_one(image_path):
    image_one.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_path))

def set_image_one(image_path):
    image_two.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_path))
```

Call these functions according to your requirements and pass the fetched file path into them.

Thanks